# Find if a view is on screen in a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tv

I'm working on an AndroidTV app. So I have a recyclerview that contains a horizontal linear layout with 5 items. During OnBindViewHolder I call viewholder.bind() and in there I change the width of the individual items dynamically. I then call getLocalVisibleRect() to see which of those views are actually on screen. Here is the issue though. It works for the initial screen, but when I scroll down the recyclerview, it is inconsistent with the results of if they are on screen or not. Here is where I set the length of the item and try to set it focusable if it is on screen or not.

```
    private void setProgramDataToView(Programme programme, TextView textView) {
        textView.setText(getEPGText(programme));
        textView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                Rect r = new Rect();
                boolean v = textView.getLocalVisibleRect(r);
                textView.setFocusable(v);
                textView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = textView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = timeLineHelper.getDurationProgram(programme);
        textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
```

I've tried to change the GlobalLayoutListener to before or after changing the length, it doesn't make a difference it seems like. And since it works for the initial recyclerview items, it seems like the logic works. It seems like it could be a race condition, but while scrolling some of the items give the right results while the rest are very inconsistent. For example it will say views that are on screen are not on screen and views that are off screen are on screen. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't use [`findFirstVisibleItemPosition`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findFirstVisibleItemPosition())  and [findLastVisibleItemPosition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findLastVisibleItemPosition()) to determine the views that are on-screen?

Comment: The recyclerview is vertical, but each item has a horizontal linear layout and thats what I am looking to see which linearlayout children are on screen. I inherited this code so not sure why they did it this way. I posted my solution.

Comment: I understand that you inherited the code, but can you change it? I can post a simple way to check which `RecyclerView` layouts are on the screen if that is something that you can use. It is a standard way to do it.

Comment: I have a method that is working for me now but I would like to see yours as well to see if its better. Currently mine is pretty intensive as it sets focusability pretty often (Every time DPAD_RIGHT is pressed).

Comment: I can give you a method that, when called, will return the adapter positions of the first and last `RecyclerView` children on the screen. Can you work with that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to the `isViewOnScreen()` method that you posted. It uses the layout manager of the `RecyclerView` to bracket the views that are visible then checks to make sure the adapter position of the view in question is bracketed by these positions. See [doc for these methods](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findFirstVisibleItemPosition()).

```
private boolean isViewOnScreen(RecyclerView rv, View view) {
    // Assuming a LinearLayoutManager but it could be another type.
    LinearLayoutManager lm = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
    int firstVisiblePosition = lm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    int lastVisiblePosition = lm.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
    int viewPosition = lm.getPosition(view);
    return viewPosition >= firstVisiblePosition && viewPosition <= lastVisiblePosition;
}
```

Comment: this crashes for me when we get to the `getPosition` line

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just checking which views were on screen during OnKeyDown in the fragment the recyclerview was used in. This is a bit excessive in terms of computation but worked for my case. This ensures the view is drawn completely before checking if its on screen.

```
private boolean setOnScreenViewsFocusable(View focus) {
    View parentView = (View) focus.getParent();
    if (parentView.getId() != View.NO_ID && parentView.getId() == R.id.channel_item) {
        LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) parentView;
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            parentLayout.getChildAt(i).setFocusable(isViewOnScreen(parentLayout.getChildAt(i)));
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean isViewOnScreen(View view) {
    Rect r = new Rect();
    return view.getGlobalVisibleRect(r);
}
```